# SQL Server performance tip

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the SQL WHERE clause short-circuit evaluated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated)

I have the following question regarding this query:

```
select * from sometable 
where 1=1 or (select count(*) from table2 > 0)
```

If the first condition is true (`1=1`), does SQL Server still do the inner select? 
Or does it stop when the first condition is true (like C)

Comment: It's a **query** - not a sentence...

Comment: What does the execution plan say?

Comment: I don't think this a duplicate. 1=1 is not the same as IS NULL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It stops when the (1=1) is true. You can check easily using Ctrl-M then Ctrl-E

Consider this query

```
select * from master..spt_values
where 1=1 or (select count(*) from master..sysobjects) > 0
```

The execution plan only shows a scan in `master..spt_values` and no activity in `sysobjects`.

Contrary to C, it does not stop when the **LEFTMOST** condition is true, instead the query optimizer works out **independently of order presented** which is the least cost to evaluate. In the case of the constants `1 vs 1` the winner is clear.

Comment: But is this due to the fact that it's a constant comparison that can be optimized to always evaluate to true? I get the feeling that the OP is asking the broader question of whether or not the `where` clause short circuits.

Comment: @Adam I get that impression too - this query form is commonly used for optional parameters

Answer (score 5):

It is short circuited only because you are comparing literals. The optimiser detects this trivial comparison.

But if you have [forced parameterisation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175037.aspx) set then the literals are changed to parameters and SQL Server works on a general case that each side could be different. Subject to the long list of conditions for forced parameterisation...

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, [SQL Server does not guarantee boolean operator short-circuit](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/). Do not write queries that rely on boolean short-circuit for performance or correctness.

Answer (score 0):

I will point out that you may get different results if you say where 1=1 or id = 10, I know I added the 1=1 to a query and got different results. I would not use 1=1 with an OR clause under any circumstances.