# Does an AND statement in SQL always get executed?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, core-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the SQL WHERE clause short-circuit evaluated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated)

If we do

```
SELECT * FROM Business WHERE Latitude < 9 AND Latitude > 10
```

for example, will `Latitude > 10` ever be called if Latitude is `8` for example?

What about in mysql?

What about in core data?

Is it dependent on SQL implementation or is there a definite standard that in where clause if one of the `AND` statement is false than the rest won't be executed.

I asked this to know whether I can save some computational power. Say the expression after the first AND is expensive to compute such as computing distance.

Comment: Both sides of the `and` operator are evaluated. The query in your example would never return any rows, as a value can not be less than nine and more than ten at the same time. (I have just verified this in MySQL to be sure.)

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING: down-to-earth answer**

You have probably mistaken AND with OR (in fact condition `Latitude < 9 AND Latitude > 10` makes no sense..).

- **OR conjunction** AFAIK in most languages this is implemented as follows: every condition is checked until one is true (i believe this is also true with SQL - **EDIT**: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated/909770#909770) suggests that the actual behaviour is *implementation-dependant*, i.e. you can't take that for sure in any RDBMS)
- **AND conjunction** every condition is checked until one is false

So you probably wanted to write this condition:

```
Latitude < 9 OR Latitude > 10
```

which is equivalent to:

```
NOT(Latitude >= 9 AND Latitude <= 10)
```

Comment: Latitude < 9 OR Latitude > 10 is equivalent to: NOT( Latitude >= 9 AND Latitude <= 10 )

Comment: A small comment: Not, Not equal usually hurt performance, so "Latitude < 9 OR Latitude > 10" is more preferable