# OR condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

```
WHERE ConditionA OR ConditionB OR ConditionC
```

Does it execute ConditionB or ConditionC if ConditionA is true?

**EDIT**

Here is the actual condition which in a TVF. I want to make sure whether my complex query is not executing if MustNotHaveAllConditions is null or empty.

```
@MustNotHaveAllConditions = '' OR @MustNotHaveAllConditions IS NULL OR
Patient.Id NOT IN 
( ... complex sql query
)
```

Comment: Give the full example code. Did you check the query plan?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you asking what result set will be returned, or are you asking if the Sql Engine actually executes the condition to check if the condition is true if the first condition already is true?

Comment: So if A is true and C is true you will get back records for A and C.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: query plan does not specify this

Comment: Is `@MustNotHaveAllConditions` logically independent of the `NOT IN` subquery or is one dependent on the other in some way?

Comment: This question apparently has been asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated. The consensus seems to be that short-circuit evaluation is not guaranteed in SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. But make sure that in some cases optimizer could change the operands order