# Using CASE in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am having trouble using CASE when attempting to return the appropriate results based on whether a certain value is passed.

For example I would like to run a query if the suburb is passed

```
WHEN @suburb <> '' THEN
@suburb 
END
= [Suburb]
AND 
[City] = @city
```

However how do I only run the query so that when no suburb is passed it only uses the city?

Should I rather write the query as follows?

```
WHERE
(
    [Suburb] = @suburb
    AND
    [City] = @city
)
OR
(
    [City] = @city
)
```

Comment: I definitely would not write it in the second form.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - Why would not recommend writing it in the second from?

Comment: Because why repeat the `City = @city` clause twice?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - I did think about that after I had posted it however is the logic inappropriate apart from the repetition?

Comment: No, but there are probably dozens of ways you could write the query and get the right results. That doesn't make all of them appropriate. Don't just think about correct logic or even performance, think about readability too.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - May be a n00b question. How do you know whether it is logical if the results you are getting is what is required?

Comment: I didn't say your query wasn't logical. I simply recommended not writing it that way because it is redundant. Follow the DRY principle when you can (don't repeat yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need `CASE`:

```
WHERE (suburb = @suburb OR @suburb = '' OR @suburb IS NULL) AND city = @city
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. A question though as I a newbie to SQL. I am guessing that the OR statement is only fulfilled if the first condition fails e.g. if `suburb = @suburb` does not have a value only the does it then proceed to process `@suburb = ''`. Is thar right?

Comment: No, SQL does not short-circuit. All expressions are evaluated.

Comment: The article at http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2003/11/14/513.aspx seems to suggest it does unless I have misunderstood. If all conditions are evaluated, is it posisble that all those conditions can be met?

Comment: I'm not sure where that article implies that short-circuiting is guaranteed, but it is not, not even inside CASE. Please read this entire question and its answers: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12941/does-sql-server-read-all-of-a-coalesce-function-even-if-the-first-argument-is-no/12945#12945

Comment: I stand corrected. SQL does not *reliably* short-circuit. Good discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand & John Pick - Thanks guys.

Comment: @John Pick I would even state it the other way around, sort of. *SQL Server may short circuit, but don't rely on it.*

Comment: @John Pick - When do you use `CASE`?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey MSDN has some good examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using SQL Server 2008, you'll want to use the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint here to avoid caching an inappropriate plan. See [Catch-all queries](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) for more details.

```
...
WHERE ((@suburb = '') OR (@suburb <> '' AND [Suburb] = @suburb))
    AND [City] = @city
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few alternative ways to achieve, you can try one of these..

```
WHERE [City] = @city
AND ([Suburb] = @suburb  OR '' = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, TelephoneNumber, "When to Contact" = 
 CASE
      WHEN TelephoneSpecialInstructions IS NULL THEN 'Any time'
      ELSE TelephoneSpecialInstructions
 END
```

FROM Person.vAdditionalContactInfo;