# Short circuit evaluation for SQL query optimisation

Tags: sql, query-optimization, short-circuiting

I want to optimize my query using short circuit evaluation as below:

Query 1:

```
Select emp_id, emp_name 
From emp_table 
Where emp_name = "xyz" 
and emp_id >= 50;
```

Query 2 :

```
Select emp_id, emp_name 
From emp_table 
Where emp_name = "xyz" 
and (emp_id >= 50 or 1 = 0);
```

Will the addition of `or 1 = 0` condition (short circuit evaluation) in query 2 result in optimization?
How exactly would the short circuit evaluation work in above example?

Comment: Related, and IMO a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated

Answer (score 1):

it won't result in optimization (well,, it could in case there is a bug in the database engine and this would workaround the bug ;)

but i don't thing this question has anything to do with [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) - `0 and ?`,  `1 or ?` are short circuit evaluated, not `1 = 0`,  `0 or ?`, `1 and ?` nor `? and (? or 1 = 0)`

plus the engine should delete `or 1 = 0` from your query during compile time (= optimize the query), but i don't know how to inspect the resulting bytecode, so i'm not sure about this...