# Short-circuit logic evaluation operators

Tags: mysql, sql, logic, short-circuiting

Are there any short-circuit logic operators (specifically short-circuit `AND` and short-circuit `OR`) that I can use in a `WHERE` clause in MySQL 5.5? If there isn't, what are the alternatives?

An abstract view at my problem along with an explanation as to why I need this can be found at this fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97fd1/3

In reality we are looking at millions of books in millions of bookstores in thousands of cities in hundreds of countries, which is why we cannot accept the overhead of receiving the unneeded information with every query we dispatch  and seriously need to find a way to make the evaluation stop as soon as we have all rows that satisfy the current condition, before moving on to the next OR.

Let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance.

---

As requested, here is the schema used in the fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE quantitycache (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  quantity INT,
  book_id INT NOT NULL,
  bookstore_id INT NULL,
  city_id INT NULL,
  country_id INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

As well as some example data:

```
INSERT INTO quantitycache 
     (quantity, book_id, bookstore_id, city_id, country_id)
VALUES
     (5,        1,       1,            NULL,    NULL),
     (100,      2,       1,            NULL,    NULL),
     (7,        1,       2,            NULL,    NULL),
     (12,       1,       NULL,         1,       NULL),
     (12,       1,       NULL,         NULL,    1),
     (100,      2,       NULL,         1,       NULL),
     (100,      2,       NULL,         NULL,    1),
     (200,      3,       NULL,         1,       NULL),
     (250,      3,       NULL,         NULL,    1);
```

Comment: The only way you are going to be able to do this is using T-SQL me thinks. If you write a query that queries ALL stores then you will have a long wait BUT with T-SQL you can set variables and flags etc to break out of a loop that iteratively executes a smaller portion of the query (i.e. query store by store) once a match is found.

Comment: I'll bet that it will stop evaluating an `OR` expression as soon as one of the cases matches, as long as none of the expressions has side effects.

Comment: @Barmar: This is not true unfortunately, as you can see in the fiddle, the rows that satisfy the other OR conditions are returned as well.

Comment: That's what `OR` means -- return rows that satisfy any of the conditions.

Comment: Indeed, which is why I am asking if there is a way to use short-circuit logic operators instead of eager operators.

Comment: @Barmar - this may OR may not be true (lol) just because either side may or may not be true does not mean that SQL server will not evaluate both sides of the expression. I suggest the OP looks at CASE statement deterministic evaluation (google "T-SQL short circuit logic")

Comment: I think you want something involving `IF()`, but I can't understand your logic so I'm not sure what the full expression is.

Comment: Please copy the schema and attempted query to your question, and include the desired result.

Comment: see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/cb536df3-f573-49eb-b886-7ca8e899a4dd

Comment: And I would hazard a guess this is pretty standard. The only way to short ciruit is by T-SQL and even that will be a bit of a minefield see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2011/03/03/don-t-depend-on-expression-short-circuiting-in-t-sql-not-even-with-case.aspx

Comment: Also see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated

Comment: I know it's an old question, but..is it ever be possibile to separate the "big table" into smaller tables? For example, one with books-vs-stores relations, one for stores-vs-cities and another with cities-vs-countries. This way the queries could be simplified a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that a query does not execute imperatively.  The query you wrote may run on multiple threads, and therefore a short-circuit operator in the where clause would not result in only one result.

Instead, use the `LIMIT` clause to only return the first row.

```
SELECT * FROM quantitycache
WHERE bookstore_id = 1 OR city_id = 1 OR country_id = 1
ORDER BY bookstore_id IS NULL ASC,
         city_id IS NULL ASC,
         country_id IS NULL ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

---

To get the best match for all books in a result set, save the results to a temp table, find the best result, then return interesting fields.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE results (id int, book_id int, match_rank int);

INSERT INTO results (id, book_id, match_rank)
SELECT id, book_id, 
    -- this assumes that lower numbers are better
    CASE WHEN Bookstore_ID is not null then 1 
         WHEN City_ID is not null then 2 
         ELSE 3 END as match_rank
FROM quantitycache
WHERE bookstore_id = 1 OR city_id = 1 OR country_id = 1;

Select * 
from (
    select book_id, MIN(match_rank) as best_rank 
    from results 
    group by book_id
) as r
inner join results as rid 
    on r.book_id = rid.book_id 
    and rid.match_rank = r.best_rank
inner join quantitycache as q on q.id = rid.id;

DROP TABLE results;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately this would only return a single book_id, whilst we actually need to get the results for all books.

Comment: ... err but your question states to "stop as soon as we have a hit". If you need to get all results then you will have to traverse all rows @ChristianKiewiet

Comment: I think he means "stop checking columns in the `OR` as soon as one is satisfied".

Comment: Let me rephrase that to "as soon as we have all rows that satisfy the current condition"

Comment: You can't know whether you have all the rows that satisfy until you check all the rows.

Comment: @ChristianKiewiet, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e34a3/1 for an example of results.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I will check the performance your attempt when I'm in the office tomorrow; even if it should perform poorly, this looks like a nudge in the right direction.