# MySQL OR operator betwen two non-null results

Tags: mysql, operators, or-operator

What happens if both values in an or statement are non-null?

Does mysql uses the left side every time or is there a possibility that mysql uses the right side?

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts p 
WHERE parent_id = ? OR id = ?
ORDER BY date 
DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Of course will mysql use the right side. Why not? Do you want the check of the id only when there's no matching parent_id at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Short-circuit logic evaluation operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969780/short-circuit-logic-evaluation-operators)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If the values are `null` then the comparison with `=` will fail. Use `IS` instead.
2. You can't really tell which condition will be executed first and how the DB handles the filtering. This is totally up to the optimizer at runtime.

Comment: I created a query that uses COALESCE( p.parent_id, p.id ). If the paren_id is NULL it will use the primary id.