# Mysql - order of the "OR" operator

Tags: mysql, logic, or-condition

In a large query, I have

```
INNER JOIN file
ON ( file.file_id = temp_student_table.converted_file 
     OR file.file_id = temp_student_table.uploaded_file)
```

If `file.file_id = temp_student_table.converted_file` is a match, does MySQL check for the second statement? what happens if both of them return a match? Does it only consider the first statement?

Comment: No. If it is `OR` and the first matches, the second does not have to be matched.

Comment: @fedorqui So if theyre both matched, it only considers the first one. Right?

Comment: Why not test it and find out? I can't take more than a minute.

Comment: @Strawberry  It matters if one of them has side effects or errors, such as divide by zero.

Comment: Depends if its a @Strawberry tree. They usually make a lot of noise..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the SQL WHERE clause short-circuit evaluated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated)

Comment: Related: [Short-circuit logic evaluation operators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16969780/2359271)

Comment: The order that MySQL checks the OR function is irrelevant.  The OR operator returns true if either or both conditions are true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an `OR` condition, it will just evaluate the first condition and exit if it is already true.

OR operator has this behaviour:

```
A | B | A OR B
0   0     0
0   1     1            0 = False
1   0     1            1 = True
1   1     1
```

This means the `A OR B` is true unless A and B are false. For this, `A OR B` will evaluate the minimum necessary: if `A` is already true, there is no point in continuing to evaluate the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an `OR` operator here it checks for the first condition.If the first statement is matched then it proceeds.The second one need not be matched in the condtion

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql, OR will return true:

- if the first operand is true, in that case the second operand won't be tested
- if the first operand is false and the second one is true