# CASE and COALESCE short-circuit evaluation works with sequences in PL/SQL but not in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sequence

Does the short-circuit evaluation described in the documentation for `CASE` and `COALESCE()` apply to sequences when used in SQL? This does not appear to be happening.

The Oracle [documentation on `CASE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037) states that:

> Oracle Database uses short-circuit evaluation. For a simple `CASE` expression... Oracle never evaluates a comparison_expr if a previous comparison_expr is equal to expr. For a searched CASE expression, the database... never evaluates a condition if the previous condition was true.

Similarly for `COALESCE()` [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions030.htm#SQLRF51282) states that:

> Oracle Database uses short-circuit evaluation. The database evaluates each expr value and determines whether it is NULL, rather than evaluating all of the expr values before determining whether any of them is NULL.

When calling a sequence from SQL this does not appear to be the case; as you can see no short circuiting occurs and the sequence is incremented.

```
SQL> create sequence tmp_test_seq start with 1 increment by 1;
SQL> select tmp_test_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1
SQL> select tmp_test_seq.currval from dual;

   CURRVAL
----------
         1
SQL> select coalesce(1, tmp_test_seq.nextval) from dual;

COALESCE(1,TMP_TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL)
--------------------------------
                               1
SQL> select tmp_test_seq.currval from dual;

   CURRVAL
----------
         2
SQL> select case when 1 = 1 then 1 else tmp_test_seq.nextval end as s from dual;


         S
----------
         1
SQL> select tmp_test_seq.currval from dual;

   CURRVAL
----------
         3
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf9e6/1).

However, when calling from PL/SQL the sequence is **not** incremented:

```
SQL> create sequence tmp_test_seq start with 1 increment by 1;
SQL> declare
  2     i number;
  3  begin
  4     i := tmp_test_seq.nextval;
  5     dbms_output.put_line(tmp_test_seq.currval);
  6     i := coalesce(1, tmp_test_seq.nextval);
  7     dbms_output.put_line(i);
  8     dbms_output.put_line(tmp_test_seq.currval);
  9     i := case when 1 = 1 then 1 else tmp_test_seq.nextval end;
 10     dbms_output.put_line(i);
 11     dbms_output.put_line(tmp_test_seq.currval);
 12  end;
 13  /
1
1
1
1
1
SQL> select tmp_test_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         2
```

Calling the sequence in SQL from PL/SQL the same results as with SQL happens:

```
SQL> create sequence tmp_test_seq start with 1 increment by 1;
SQL> declare
  2     i number;
  3  begin
  4     select tmp_test_seq.nextval into i from dual;
  5     dbms_output.put_line(tmp_test_seq.currval);
  6     select coalesce(1, tmp_test_seq.nextval) into i from dual;
  7     dbms_output.put_line(i);
  8     dbms_output.put_line(tmp_test_seq.currval);
  9     select case when 1 = 1 then 1 else tmp_test_seq.nextval end into i
 10       from dual;
 11     dbms_output.put_line(i);
 12     dbms_output.put_line(tmp_test_seq.currval);
 13  end;
 14  /
1
1
2
1
3
```

There doesn't seem to be anything in the documentation about this; [the Administrator's guide for managing sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/views.htm#ADMIN11792), [the SQL language reference on sequence psuedocolumns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns002.htm#SQLRF00253), [the PL/SQL language reference on CURRVAL and NEXTVAL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS00610) or [the database concepts overview of sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/schemaob.htm#CNCPT611).

Does the short-circuit evaluation of `CASE` and `COALESCE()` occur for sequences when used in SQL? Is this documented?

We're on 11.2.0.3.5 if it's of interest.

Comment: Testing in SQL Server. `NEXT VALUE FOR function cannot be used within CASE, CHOOSE, COALESCE, IIF, ISNULL and NULLIF.` which is one way of avoiding it I guess!

Comment: That's a question for the Metalink i guess.

Comment: I'd be surprised if no one noticed this before... @Alan. I've managed to find 2331433 on metalink, which looks similar(ish), but only on CASE and not COALESCE. I love Oracle's response as well, not that helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explanation of why the short-circuit evaluation does not apply to sequences might be the following. What is a sequence? Putting internals aside, it's a combination of sequence definition(record in `seq$` data dictionary table) and some internal SGA component, it's not a function and might be considered, although the documentation [does not state it directly](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15858/tgsql_sqlproc.htm#TGSQL184)(but execution plan does) as row source. And every time a sequence is being referenced directly in the select list of a query, it has to be evaluated by the optimizer when it searches for optimal execution plan. During the process of forming an optimal execution plan a sequence gets incremented if `nextval` pseudocolumn is referenced:

```
SQL> create sequence seq1;
Sequence created
```

Here is our sequence:

```
SQL> select o.obj#
  2       , o.name
  3       , s.increment$
  4       , s.minvalue
  5       , s.maxvalue
  6       , s.cache
  7    from sys.seq$ s
  8    join sys.obj$ o
  9       on (o.obj# = s.obj#)
 10    where o.name = 'SEQ1'
 11  ;


      OBJ# NAME    INCREMENT$   MINVALUE   MAXVALUE      CACHE
---------- ------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     94442 SEQ1             1          1       1E28         20
```

Lets trace below query, and also take a look at its execution plan

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context forever, level 4';
Session altered

SQL> select case
  2           when 1 = 1 then 1
  3           when 2 = 1 then seq1.nextval
  4         end as res
  5    from dual;

       RES
----------
         1

/* sequence got incremented by 1 */

SQL> select seq1.currval from dual;

   CURRVAL
----------
         3
```

Trace file information:

> STAT #1016171528 id=1 cnt=1 pid=0 pos=1 obj=94442 **op='SEQUENCE  SEQ1** ...
>   STAT #1016171528 id=2 cnt=1 pid=1 pos=1 obj=0 **op='FAST DUAL**  ...
>   CLOSE #1016171528:c=0,e=12,dep=0,type=0,tim=12896600071500 /* close the cursor */

The execution plan will show us basically the same:

```
SQL> explain plan for select case
  2                            when 1 = 1 then 1
  3                            else seq1.nextval
  4                          end
  5                      from dual
  6  /
Explained
Executed in 0 seconds

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display());
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
---------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 51561390
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SEQUENCE        | SEQ1 |       |            |          |
|   2 |   FAST DUAL      |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
9 rows selected
Executed in 0.172 seconds
```

<strike>In terms of evaluation, referencing a sequence directly in a query, roughly the same as including a correlated sub-query. That correlated sub-query will always be evaluated by the optimizer:</strike>

```
SQL> explain plan for select case
  2                            when 1 = 1 then 1
  3                            when 2 = 1 then (select 1
  4                                               from dual)
  5                          end as res
  6                      from dual;
Explained
Executed in 0 seconds

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display());
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1317351201
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |     1 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  FAST DUAL       |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |  FAST DUAL       |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
9 rows selected
Executed in 0.063 seconds
```

We can see that `dual` table has been included in the execution plan twice.

The analogy with a sub-query was made in a rush. There are more differences than similarities, of course. Sequences are absolutely different mechanisms. But, a sequences are viewed by the optimizer as a row source, and as long as it doesn't see the `nextval` pseudocolumn of a sequence being directly referenced in the `select` list of a top-level query, it won't evaluate the sequence, otherwise sequence will be incremented, whether a short-circuit evaluation logic is being used or not. PL/SQL engine,obviously, (starting from Oracle 11g r1) has a different way to access a sequence value. Should be noted that in previous 11gR1 versions of RDBMS  we should write a query to reference a sequence in PL/SQL block, which PL/SQL engine sent directly to the SQL engine.

The answer to the "*why a sequence gets incremented during generating an execution plan by the optimizer*" question, lies in the internal implementation of sequences.

Comment: I think the short-circuit problem is not related to the sequence nextval, which is always evaluated in a SELECT statement, as per [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/queries009.htm#SQLRF20036), but in the `case` and `coalesce` implementation of the Oracle SQL engine

Comment: With your changed answer you're actually indicating that Nicholas is correct it seems @mucio, you're insinuating that it's a query... and that's why the short-circuiting doesn't work.

Comment: Your question "Does the short-circuit evaluation of CASE and COALESCE() occur for sequences when used in SQL? Is this documented?" Nicholas said "In terms of evaluation, referencing a sequence directly in a query, roughly the same as including a correlated sub-query". This is not true, because with WHERE... OR... (in my demo) you can use short-circuiting with a sub-query. My corrected answer is: Oracle states that nextval in a SELECT is always evaluated (and only once), CASE/Coalesce behave differently in a SELECT statement (in a simple SQL or in a PL/SQL block) than used as function in PL/SQL

Comment: @mucio Yes, saying `always` was a bit over-the-top. Now, the `where` clause is absolutely a different story. It solely up to the optimizer how predicates in the `where` clause are going to be evaluated . The short-circuit cannot be guarantied. [Here is an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/789b4/2) when short-circuit evaluation fails.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I think in your last case you have a situation like the one in my first answer, the code returns an error, but probably before the optimizer is called in action. I think (1/0) is calculated/checked before to do any table access, in case you access a table the story is different: [here for example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/789b4/4)

Answer (score 5):

For PL/SQL Oracle assures that it will use short-circuit evaluation:

> When evaluating a logical expression, PL/SQL uses short-circuit
>   evaluation. That is, PL/SQL stops evaluating the expression as soon as
>   it can determine the result. Therefore, you can write expressions that
>   might otherwise cause errors.

From: [2 PL/SQL Language Fundamentals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS258)

When you use the `nextval` in SQL code, we have a different situation.

First of all we have to keep in mind that `currval` and `nextval` are pseudocolumns:

> A pseudocolumn behaves like a table column, but is not actually stored
>   in the table. You can select from pseudocolumns, but you cannot
>   insert, update, or delete their values. A pseudocolumn is also similar
>   to a function without arguments (please refer to Chapter 5,
>   "Functions". However, functions without arguments typically return the
>   same value for every row in the result set, whereas pseudocolumns
>   typically return a different value for each row.

From: [3 Pseudocolumns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns.htm).

The question now is: why Oracle evaluate `nextval`? or Is this behaviour stated somewhere?

> Within a single SQL statement containing a reference to NEXTVAL,
>   Oracle increments the sequence once:
>
> - For each row returned by the outer query block of a SELECT statement.    Such a query block can appear in the following places:
>
>   1. A top-level SELECT statement
>   2. An INSERT ... SELECT statement (either single-table or multitable).    For a multitable insert, the reference to NEXTVAL must
>        appear in the    VALUES clause, and the sequence is updated once for
>        each row returned by the subquery, even though NEXTVAL may be
>        referenced in multiple    branches of the multitable insert.
>   3. A CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT statement
>   4. A CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ... AS SELECT statement
> - For each row updated in an UPDATE statement
> - For each INSERT statement containing a VALUES clause
> - For each row merged by a MERGE statement. The reference to NEXTVAL can appear in the merge_insert_clause or the merge_update_clause or
>     both. The NEXTVALUE value is incremented for each row updated and for
>     each row inserted, even if the sequence number is not actually used in
>     the update or insert operation. If NEXTVAL is specified more than once
>     in any of these locations, then the sequence is incremented once for
>     each row and returns the same value for all occurrences of NEXTVAL for
>     that row.

From: [Sequence Pseudocolumns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns002.htm#i1009336)

Your case is clearly "1. A top-level SELECT statement", but it doesn't mean that the short-circuit logic is not in place, but only that `nextval` is always evaluated.

If you are interested to the short-circuit logic, then it's better to remove the `nextval` from the equation.

A query like this doesn't evaluate the subquery:

```
select 6 c
  from dual
where  'a' = 'a' or 'a' = (select dummy from dual)
```

But if try to do something similar with `coalesce` or `case` we will see that the Oracle Optimizer decides to execute the subqueries:

```
select 6 c
  from dual
where  'a' = coalesce('a', (select dummy from dual) )
```

I created annotated tests in [this demo in SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf9e6/119) to show this.

It looks like Oracle applies the short-circuit logic only if with OR condition, but with `coalesce` and `case` it has to evaluate all branches.

I think your first tests in PL/SQL shows that `coalsce` and `case` use a short-circuit logic in PL/SQL, as Oracle states. Your second test, including the sequence in SQL statements, shows that in that case the `nextval` is evaluated anyway, even if the result is not used, and Oracle also documents that.

Putting together the two things looks a bit odd, because `coalesce` and `case` behaviour seems to be really inconsistent too me too, but we have also to keep in mind that the implementation of that logic is implementation dependent ([here my source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated))

Comment: `I was able to convince the optimizer to not evaluate the sequence nextval` where exactly did it happen? Sorry couldn't find it in your SQL fiddle.

Comment: The last query returns an error (ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here), even if a numeric values is allowed there (the query just before that uses `CHR(64 +1)`). So my explanation, but I will be happy to know there is a better one, is that for the last query the Optimizer behaviour is different. `nextval`is not evaluated, but  this doesn't allow Oracle to compile the query. As you can see I used `nextval` without problems in a `SELECT FROM DUAL` (2nd query) and inside a `COALESCE` and `CHR` (4th query), so I concluded the problem is that, inside a subquery, `nextval` is not evaluated

Comment: Unfortunately it has nothing to do with short circuit evaluation. The last query returns that error simply because it's not allowed to use sequences in a sub-query, and [documentation states it](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm#ADMIN11800) very clearly.

Comment: You are right, thank you for pointing out that, I'll modify my answer with some new tests