# LISTAGG is evaluated and fails in an unreachable case statement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, case, listagg

I've experienced some very unusual behaviour with the LISTAGG function in Oracle.

I'm aware that LISTAGG fails if it deals with over 4000 characters.

Because I know this, I had a CASE statement to replace cells with counts of more than 100 characters with a "Too many to count" message.

```
CREATE TABLE EMP (
  ID  VARCHAR2(401),
  DEP VARCHAR2(10)
);

INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (DBMS_RANDOM.string('A', 401), 'FOO'); -- Run exactly 9 times
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (DBMS_RANDOM.string('A', 5), 'BAR');   -- Run 3 times
```

For simplicities sake, let's ignore my special case for counts > 100, and just say that FOO should be excluded, and BAR should be included.

```
SELECT DEP,
  CASE
    WHEN DEP = 'BAR' THEN
      LISTAGG(ID, ',')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL)
        OVER (PARTITION BY DEP)
    ELSE
      'Too many to count'
  END AS ID_LIST
FROM EMP;
```

This provides results that should look like this (but with different random characters):

[image: Success]

However, adding just a single extra row, bringing the total in the FOO department to 10...

```
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (DBMS_RANDOM.string('A', 401), 'FOO'); -- Same as before
```

Causes us to meet with an exception when re-running the same select:

```
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long  
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"  
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.  
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.
```

Strangely, this happens even if the condition in the case statement is changed to 1=2.

I'm not sure what's happening here. It seems that SQL decides to evaluate the statement regardless of whether or not it has any intention of using it, so fails when it is met with the 4000+ character LISTAGG.

I've got a few solutions to my problem, but I'd really like to know more about why SQL decided to (apparently) run the LISTAGG even though it should never get reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final evaluation of the select list columns/expressions, including the short-circuited case expression, happens after the data has been retrieved. Any grouping etc. has already been done by that point.

This effect doesn't only happen with `listagg()`, it can be seen with any aggregate or analytic function call in the return expression - though it's hard to spot unless there are side effects.

As a demo I created a simple package that has a function I can call from the the query:

```
create package p as
  n number := 0;
  function f return number;
end;
/

create package body p as
  function f return number as
  begin
    n := n + 1;
    return n;
  end;
end;
/
```

This is essentially emulating a session-specific sequence; sequences also demonstrate this behaviour, [but appearently for a different reason](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20550512/266304) so I didn't want to use one for this.

Calling that function inside the case expression does what you'd expect; it is only called when the condition is matched:

```
select dep,
  case
    when dep = 'BAR' then
      p.f
    else
      -1
  end as id_list
from emp;

DEP        ID_LIST
---------- -------
FOO             -1
...
BAR              1
BAR              2
BAR              3
FOO             -1

select p.f from dual;

         F
----------
         4
```

The function was only called when the condition was matched. The execution plan for that shows just a full table scan:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |    13 |    91 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    13 |    91 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

With an aggregate call instead:

```
select dep,
  case
    when dep = 'BAR' then
      count(p.f)
    else
      -1
  end as id_list
from emp
group by dep;

DEP        ID_LIST
---------- -------
FOO             -1
BAR              3

select p.f from dual;

         F
----------
        18

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |    13 |    91 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY     |      |    13 |    91 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    13 |    91 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

... the function was called 13 times instead of 3; the plan shows the hash group by step, which has to have happened across all of the retrieved rows before the case is evaluated.

Similarly for an analytic version:

```
select dep,
  case
    when dep = 'BAR' then
      count(p.f) over (partition by dep)
    else
      -1
  end as id_list
from emp;

DEP        ID_LIST
---------- -------
BAR              3
BAR              3
BAR              3
FOO             -1
...

select p.f from dual;

         F
----------
        32

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |    13 |    91 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  WINDOW SORT       |      |    13 |    91 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    13 |    91 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

... again the function was called 13 times, as the window sort (and hence the analytic calculation) was done before the case expression could be evaluated.

So the issue is not really that the return expression (`listagg()` in your case) is being evaluated within the case expression when it shouldn't be; it's being evaluated and throwing the exception before the case expression conditions are even considered.

Comment: It is still strange that the optimizer is not doing a better job when the first `when` condition in the case statement is `1=0`. The optimizer should rewrite `case when 1=0 then <whatever> else 'Too many to count' end as id_list` to `'Too many to count' as id_list` before the whole thing even goes to compilation. The optimizer is pretty clever that way in other parts of parsing queries, but apparently not so in this case.

Comment: There's a MOS note suggesting it should do optimisation for number comparison (so 1=0), but not for string comparison ('T'='F'). But even so that must be too late in the process - it would do that in the non-aggregate version but the scale of that query rewrite might be too much when it has to worry about aggregation etc. Maybe it's just too niche for them to have looked at...

Comment: Thanks Alex, that was a very thorough explanation. I should have thought to do an explain plan on this myself.