# SQL OR statement hit when previous condition is true - Full Text Search

Tags: sql, full-text-search

In the query below I would expect the `OR CONTAINS(d.Data, @SearchText)` never to be reached due to `@SearchText` being set to `NULL`. However running this query throws a 
**"Null or empty full-text predicate."**
 error because the `CONTAINS(d.Data, @SearchText)` is called with a null value for @SearchText.

Any ideas why the second part of the OR statement is called when the first part is true?

```
DECLARE @searchText nvarchar(300);
set @SearchText = null

SELECT * FROM Person p      
        JOIN PersonDocument pd ON p.Id = pd.PersonId
        JOIN Document d ON d.Id = pd.DocumentId
    WHERE @SearchText IS NULL OR CONTAINS(d.Data, @SearchText)
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working in the end like this:

```
DECLARE @searchText nvarchar(300);
set @SearchText = null -- imagine this parameter was passed in null
IF @SearchText is null
BEGIN
    SET @SearchText = '""'
END 

SELECT * FROM Person p      
        JOIN PersonDocument pd ON p.Id = pd.PersonId
        JOIN Document d ON d.Id = pd.DocumentId
    WHERE @SearchText = '""' OR CONTAINS(d.Data, @SearchText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Contains will get called because it's an OR statement, even if it the value wasn't null it would still get called due to the OR statement, I think you need a guard statement such as:

```
WHERE @SearchText IS NULL OR @SearchText IS NOT NULL AND CONTAINS(d.Data, @SearchText)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - however I'm getting the same problem with the additional guard.