# Varchar-to-Datetime conversion error - fine in SELECT but breaks in WHERE

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple CTE that pulls dates from a table - the dates (`ApptDateTime`) are stored in `YYYY-MM-DDZHH:mm:SS` format. Some columns have NULL values, so I want to ignore them, along with anything that isn't really a date.

If I do:

```
;WITH cte
AS
(SELECT
        urn,
        CONVERT(DATETIME, ApptDateTime) AS ApptDateTime

    FROM data
    WHERE ISDATE(ApptDateTime) = 1  
)

SELECT
    *
FROM cte
ORDER BY ApptDateTime
```

... this works fine; I get a list of records back, ordered by date. However, if I want to see only dates that are before today and introduce a `WHERE`:

```
;WITH cte
AS
(SELECT
        urn,
        CONVERT(DATETIME, ApptDateTime) AS ApptDateTime

    FROM data
    WHERE ISDATE(ApptDateTime) = 1  
)

SELECT
    *
FROM cte
WHERE ApptDateTime < GETDATE()
ORDER BY ApptDateTime
```

I get the error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I can't see any dodgy non-date, non-NULL values in the table, and even if there were I'd expect anything that wasn't able to be `CONVERT`ed to cause an issue as part of the `SELECT` in the CTE. However, it only throws that error when I'm trying to compare the datetime. This seems so simple that I'm certain I'm missing something blindingly obvious - but I can't see it.

EDIT: If I send the results to a temp table, and then do the comparison on that ... it works fine!

```
SELECT
    urn,
    convert(datetime,ApptDateTime) as ApptDateTime
    into #temp FROM data
    WHERE ISDATE(ApptDateTime) = 1  


SELECT
    *
FROM #temp
WHERE ApptDateTime < getdate()
ORDER BY ApptDateTime

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: maybe the nulls are a problem, have you tried something like where isnull(ApptDateTime, '20990101') < getdate() ?

Comment: Same error with that included I'm afraid - I've also tried adding `AppDateTime IS NOT NULL` to the `WHERE` clause in the CTE

Comment: it should not make a difference but have you tried where ApptDateTime < convert(datetime, getdate())

Comment: Same :( I really can't understand why: the date should have already been converted during the CTE.

Comment: There's no guarantee that SQL Server won't attempt to perform the comparison *before* assessing the `ISDATE()` function call. Unfortunately, it's a [long standing issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) with little sign that they'll ever fix it. If you're on SQL Server 2012 or later, you can wrap all accesses to the column with `TRY_CONVERT` calls which then just let you deal with data or `NULL`s.

Comment: Thanks. I've managed to get it working by using a temp table (see above), but it still seems mad that it'll convert the dates for a `SELECT` but not when comparing them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever would it help to move the isdate() function to the select clause ? someghing like CASE when isdate() then convert() else '20990101' end ?

Comment: Using `CASE` *may* work but even then it's a tad flaky. I'd usually (against usual best practice) split the query into two completely separate ones - the first populates a table variable with values that pass the `ISDATE` test, and then the second query can safely convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding condition like this : `WHERE (CASE WHEN ISDATE(ApptDateTime) = 1 THEN ApptDateTime ELSE NULL END) < GETDATE()` 
I faced same issue before couple of days and solved by adding `CASE`.
Not clear about how SQL executes where condition.
I also need to find actual reason for the same. If I find anything, I will post in same post.

*Edit:* If you see in execution plan of your actual query, it will show you ApptDateTime < GETDATE() before ISDATE(ApptDateTime) = 1 which causing the error.

Reason is WHERE clause doesn't follow short-circuit rule. Ref: [Is the SQL WHERE clause short-circuit evaluated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated)

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks, and thank you to everyone for the comments, I've learned something new.