# Use of OR operator with WHERE

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, rdbms

I have studied that DBMS won't evaluate the second condition in a WHERE clause if the first condition is met.

```
select *

from student

where name = 'ABC' or name ='XYZ';



select *

from student

where name = 'ABC' or 'XYZ';
```

The first returns all the rows with name 'ABC' and 'XYZ' while second one returns just the rows with name 'ABC'.

Comment: I think it should be `where name in ('ABC', 'XYZ');`

Comment: "I have studied that DBMS won't evaluate the second condition" Where? What authoritative documentation did you read? This is not so in SQL. PS `name = 'ABC' or 'XYZ'` parses `(name = 'ABC') or  'XYZ'` & is ORing a boolean & a string, not 2 booleans.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite treats Boolean expressions as `0` for `False` and `1` for `True`.
Also converts implicitly string values to numbers when necessary in expressions like:

```
name = 'ABC' or 'XYZ'
```

in order to evaluate them.
So the above expression is equivalent to:

```
(name = 'ABC') or 'XYZ'
```

and so `'XYZ'` is implicitly converted to the numeric value of `0` meaning `False`.
The result of this expression is:

```
(name = 'ABC') or False
```

which is equivalent to:

```
name = 'ABC'
```

This is why it *returns just the rows with name 'ABC'*

Answer (score 1):

In second query `XYZ` is treated as condition(XYZ - false):

```
select *
from student
where name = 'ABC' or 'XYZ';

<=>

select *
from student
where name = 'ABC' or false;

<=>

select *
from student
where name = 'ABC';
```

> *"I have studied that DBMS won't evaluate the second condition in a WHERE clause if the first condition is met."*

It depends, [short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/909770/5070879) is not always the case.

I guess you want:

```
select *
from student
where name IN('ABC', 'XYZ'); -- basically the same as your first query
```