# How do I modify a SQL JOIN with an OR operator such that the second condition only gets evaluated when the first fails

Tags: sql, postgresql

In case table be as the row `(x=1,y=1)` and f has the rows `((x=1, y=1), (x=1, y=2))`

I want to achieve one result row only, since the first condition is met, the second ought to be ommited.

```
Select * from be join f        
ON ( (be.x = f.x AND f.y = b.y) OR (be.x = f.x))
```

Comment: Because a query is a statement of intent and not the actual way the query runs, you can only guarantee an ordering by pre-materialising. SQL is not designed to short circuit evaluation . Queries such as yours are better stated as a UNION query with separate conditions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated

Comment: This is not what the query is ment to look like in the end, if I can achive what I want with a union query, so be it, I just like to get an example.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want NOT EXISTS.

```
Select * 
from be 
join f on (be.x = f.x and f.y = be.y) 
       or (be.x = f.x and not exists (
            select 1 
            from f f2
            where be.x = f2.x and f2.y = be.y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself:

```
select distinct on (be.x)
f.y = b.y as condition_met
* from be join f 
ON ( (be.x = f.x AND f.y = b.y) OR (be.x = f.x))
order by be.x, condition_met desc
```