# Unexpected order running OR operator on SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2019

I'm having a problem when migrating from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2019.
My code

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(50) = 'all',
        @int TINYINT = 1

DECLARE @tmp TABLE (val nvarchar(MAX))
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES('123')
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES('all')

SELECT val
FROM @tmp
WHERE @str = 'ALL' OR @int = val
```

When using SQL Server 2008 R2, it's fine. The output as expected like below

```
val
123
all
```

However, when I migrate to SQL Server 2019, the error like below occurs. Besides, it just happens unusually in 2019.

> Msg 245 Level 16 State 1 Line 8 Conversion failed when converting the
> nvarchar value 'all' to data type int.

As you can see, the second condition `OR @int = val` happened unexpectedly.

I was wondering if it fails due to any breaking changes related to the order of *`OR` operator* or *`case sensitive`* `ALL` vs `all` in the next SQL Server 2008 R2 version.

---

**Updated**

Sorry for my reproduce code make you guys confuse. [This is my original code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8848cb6a68351a19d2b5c90bcd5863d7)

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. You seemed to have just been "lucky" before that you didn't get this error. `'all'` is *clearly* not a `tinyint`, and yet it will be implicitly converted to one in the `WHERE`. `@int` should be a `varchar`; you're comparing it to a datatype that can hold up to ~1Billion characters.

Comment: Nope. Actually `@tmp` table looks like `[strSplit]` [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=779a0aff7852ef748ff2e61683e12fda). So you can ignore the `val nvarchar(MAX)`. I just reproduce to make my code as simple as  possible, sir @Larnu

Comment: The code was flawed in the first place though, @NguyễnVănPhong . Like I said, you were simply lucky before . It was, in essence, a ticking time bomb.  Well *very* lucky that it didn't happen before in your production environment.

Comment: I totally agree with 2 you guys we shouldn't compare `tinyint with nvarchar(max)`. And my code should look like this `WHERE @str = 'ALL' OR (@str <> 'ALL' AND @int = val)`, right?

Comment: That won't necessarily avoid the problem either.  `@int` should be either *not* be an `tinyint` or the column `val` should be a numberical data type (and thus can't have the value `'all'`, and perhaps `NULL` instead.

Comment: But your function, `strSplit`, doesn't return a `int`, it returns `varchar(MAX)`; it's not comparable. (And, to cement it, get rid of that function and use a set based method, or the in built `STRING_SPLIT` function.)

Comment: My bad. It should be a value less than tinyint size. I just create the sample data. Because `strSplit` is used in many places. So you should ignore `tinyint, nvarchar(max)`. The root cause maybe comes from `WHERE @str = 'ALL' OR @int = val`. It should be `WHERE @str = 'ALL' OR (@str <> 'ALL' AND @int = val)` to make sure that the second OR should not be done, right? sir @AaronBertrand

Comment: `ONE MORE TIME: SQL Server does not have to follow your code left to right.` yeah. I just need the article or something like that to make sure that :)

Comment: Um, ok. [Here's an answer on this site with good info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated), and also [an article](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/understanding-t-sql-expression-short-circuiting), but you could also trust that experts answering your request for help here wouldn't be lying to you. And look, if you're willing to change your code anyway, why not just change it right?

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for your support. sir @AaronBertrand & Larnu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do two of these three things:

(

1. Either use `DECLARE @int nvarchar(max) = 1`

   OR
2. Use  `WHERE val = CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @int)`

)

AND

3. Change to using `STRING_SPLIT`. That looping function is among the least efficient methods you could ever use to split strings, even before native solutions existed. See https://sqlblog.org/split

This [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=426f7146fa41052a9ef8b69be2c1bd93) fiddle demonstrates.

And [this one](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=729970451df885766cbd829a85cdfae0) shows why `WHERE @str = 'ALL' OR (@str <> 'ALL' AND @int = val)` is not a solution. These patterns you're choosing only work if `@str` is *always* `'all'`, because they all break when it's anything else. So why have the `OR` at all?

---

You keep insisting that SQL Server should obey left to right evaluation, but we keep telling you that is simply not the case.

Here is [an article by Bart Duncan at Microsoft](https://bartduncansql.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/dont-depend-on-expression-short-circuiting-in-t-sql-not-even-with-case/), who worked on SQL Server, that you should absolutely read in full before posting any more comments or editing your question further. The critical point, though, is:

> You cannot depend on expression evaluation order for things like 
> `WHERE <expr1> OR <expr2>`
> since the optimizer might choose a plan that evaluates the second predicate before the first one.

Comment: Thanks sir. Whether the order of `OR` operator don't make sure `left to right`? So in the case of `strSplit ('all', ',')`  should be fail?

Comment: Let me explain it in more detail. Just a min sir

Comment: Herre is [my original code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8848cb6a68351a19d2b5c90bcd5863d7). Do you mean SQL Server does not have to follow your code `left to right` principle? So we will got the error when execution plan run the second condition first?

Comment: And again, it doesn't make sense to have an OR at all if the only possible way this code works is if `@str = 'all'`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c30c327270dbf26ad6537c61ec07cd91

Comment: My where clause should be like this? `WHERE @str = 'all' OR (@str <> 'all' AND @int in (SELECT val FROM dbo.strSplit(@str,',')))`

Comment: No, it should not. I've told you two ways to fix your code, and I'm not saying anything more. If you don't want to fix it right, and want to insist on believing SQL Server will always obey left to right in spite of all the evidence I've shown you that this is not the case, I can't help you.

Comment: Thanks a million, sir. I will change my code. 1. Using correct data type. 2. Using `STRING_SPLIT` feature instead of  my defined function `dbo.strSplit` 3. Don't depend on expression evaluation order for things like “WHERE OR “. Anything else sir?