# Why isn't this short circuit in lambda working?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Why linq is trying to check second expression anyway?

```
.Where(t =>  String.IsNullOrEmpty(someNullString) || t.SomeProperty >= Convert.ToDecimal(someNullstring))
```

What is usual workaround?

**Update:**
It is about LINQ to SQL, of course. It cannot translate to SQL.

Comment: I suddenly find the => and >= in this code very confusing. :-) (And I've used both quite often, but never together in the same statement.)

Comment: yes. well, thanks, i got it:)

Comment: Are you sure it isn't working? I've tested it against a list (LINQ To Objects) and seems to work.

Comment: Read the question again. Of course it works but it also evaluates the second condition while using || should have prevented this...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is the `.Where` being used on a `Table<>`?

If so, then before any data can be grabbed, it must convert the LINQ to SQL and to do that it must convert the `string` into a `decimal`. It's not trying to actually perform the comparisons yet, it's trying to build the constructs necessary to retrieve data.

Answer (score -1):

I can't reproduce any problem with the *short circuit* evaluation...

I think this evaluates to something like:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private static bool <MyMethod>b__f(MyObject t)
{
    return (String.IsNullOrEmpty(someNullString) 
                 || t.SomeProperty >= Convert.ToDecimal(someNullstring));
}
```

*short circuit* works well here.

I suspect other elements in your Enumerable evaluate the first condition (`String.IsNullOrEmpty(someNullString)`)  to false. Can you confirm this?

Provide a bit more code so that we can analyze this.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a variable **t** in any scope that may be evaluated?

Did you try with parenthesis like this:

```
.Where(t =>  (String.IsNullOrEmpty(someNullString) || 
             t.SomeProperty >= Convert.ToDecimal(someNullstring)))
```

?

Comment: The => defines the scope of t.

Answer (score -1):

There is a workaround on [The || (or) Operator in Linq with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772261/the-or-operator-in-linq-with-c-sharp) according to which you would do in your case something like:

```
.Where(t =>  t.SomeProperty >= Convert.ToDecimal(someNullstring ?? "0"))
```

Of course this might not be the solution you need in your particular case, but at least it gives an idea how to bypass the error.