# Short-circuit evaluation and LINQ-to-NHibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-sql, linq-to-nhibernate

It seems that LINQ-to-NHibernate and LINQ-to-SQL does not support short-circuit evaluation in `where` clause of query.

Am I right? 
Is there any workaround? 
May it be added to next versions of LINQ-to-NHibernate and LINQ-to-SQL?

for more information plz see followings:

[The || (or) Operator in Linq with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772261/the-or-operator-in-linq-with-c)

[Why ordinary laws in evaluting boolean expression does not fit into LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306302/why-ordinary-laws-in-evaluting-boolean-expression-does-not-fit-into-linq)

Answer (score 0):

Huh?  In LinqToSql, your c# query in code is converted to an expression tree and then a sql statement.  The sql statement is handed to mssqlserver which certainly does do short circuiting.

Also note: mssqlserver does not throw null reference exceptions.

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306302/why-ordinary-laws-in-evaluting-boolean-expression-does-not-fit-into-linq there is some problems with it...

Comment: Microsoft can't add anything to linq to sql or to sql server to resolve your problem, because it's not occuring in those layers.