# Short-circuiting in Linq-Where

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception

I have a problem in a Linq-Where method. I get a NullReferenceException in a where clause, which should not happen because C# should use short-circuiting and the second operations hould not be executed:

[image]

If `Item` is null, `Item.State == ...` should not be called, because the condition is already true (short-circuiting).

But it seems, that short-circuiting does not working in this case.

Does anyone else had and solved this problem? Thank you!

**Edit**:
In the end, the `connectionList` should not contains any null-values and no broken connections.

Comment: Do you actually *want* the nulls in the resultant list?

Comment: Looks like you want != and &&

Comment: I want the nulls, because i want to remove them from the list.

Comment: @BendEg How about `connectionList = connectionList.Where(x => x != null && x.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Broken)`? No need for a foreach loop anymore. Also, I realize this doesn't answer your specific problem.

Comment: can you post a reproducable example

Comment: Clean solution; rebuild and try again please

Comment: @BendEg Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: I dont get it, you're selecting the nulls into a list only to remove them later - why not just exclude them in the first place?!

Comment: @Jamiec Yeah I don't get that either.

Comment: Thats a good point, i try to filter at first with: `connectionList.Remove(null);`

Comment: Please state what you ACTUALLY WANT in the list at the end of all filtering. Everyone is just guessing your intent.

Comment: Never seen so many down votes on answers after watching a question for just 5 minutes.

Comment: Perhaps `Item` is not null, but `Item.State` still throws an exception.

Comment: @Jamiec Ok, i made an edit.

Comment: @Selman22 Made a good point in my answer. If || short circuits if the first condition is true, which I thought was the case that code should not have thrown. So what the frak? http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html

Comment: its because you have a `ToList()` after the `Where` selection.

Answer (score 1):

This is common problem, when querying against databases. Namely, translating short-circuiting behavior against databases, don't work the way as you would expect. You can read more about such behavior: [The || (or) Operator in Linq with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772261/the-or-operator-in-linq-with-c-sharp)

You could try this:

```
connectionList.RemoveRange(connectionList.Where(x => x==null));
connectionList.SaveChanges();
connectionList.RemoveRange(connectionList.Where(x => x.Item==BrokenState));
```

just to see if it works.