# Linq to object Multiple Where short circuit evaluation

Tags: c#, linq

When including multiple Where clauses in a Linq to object expression, will they  evaluates short-circuiting like the && operator? Meaning will condition B only be evaluated if condition A return true

For example `collection.Where(condition1).Where(condition2)`

(Not talking about Linq to sql that will not do that even with the && operator [short-circuiting-in-linq-where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900005/short-circuiting-in-linq-where))

Comment: When you ran the code and tested to see whether or not the second condition actually ran what happened?  Did it execute, or not?

Comment: if you have `SomeCollection.Where(predicate1).Where(predicate2)`, then it will be evaluated as  `SomeCollection.Where(predicate1)` (i.e., the collection may be reduced based on whether the items in the collection match the predicate.  That will return a new enumeration(possibly representing the same collection, possibly representing a reduced size collection, possibly and representing an empty collection).  Then that second predicate will be applied, and the resulting enumeration will be returned.  So, **no**

Comment: @Flydog57 If all of this "That will return a new collection (possibly the same collection, possibly a reduced size collection, possibly and empty collection)" was with *Enumeration* instead of *Collection*, it would be correct

Comment: @Flydog57 LINQ operations return *queries*, not *the results of those queries*.

Comment: When i tested it looks like it will evaluates short-circuiting, i want to know if this is how it is implemented,  i want to make sure that this will ALWAYS be the rule and i can be comfortable when doing multiple filters on properties that may be null

Comment: @JoelG If you want to know if `Where` is ever documented as yielding items where the predicate is `false` for that item, you could read the documentation, if you *really* want an official source of it.  Does the documentation for the method give you the impression that it might end up yielding items where the predicate is false?

Comment: @Servy i want to know if i can apply multiple filters on an object if evaluating condition2 when condition1 is false might throw an error

Comment: @JoelG Yes.  And to answer that question, you apparently tested it, and found that it doesn't in fact do that, and then said that you want an official guarantee that `Where` will never yield items that don't pass the predicate, at which point I asked if you'd looked at the documentation for `Where`, as that should give you the official guarantee that you want.

Comment: @Servy i did a basic search on Microsoft.com and didn't find the answer, maybe i am missing a reference

Comment: @JoelG I would suggest just searching Google, but anyways, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) is the documentation for the `Where` method.  You can see that it's documented as returning a sequence containing only the items that satisfy the condition.

Comment: @Servy i was looking on something concrete like the test Camilo Terevinto did that proovs it 100%, (or any documentation that i didn't find) i just didn't have the idea how to go about it...

Comment: @JoelG But you [said earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53771135/linq-to-object-multiple-where-short-circuit-evaluation/53771199?noredirect=1#comment94394245_53771135) that you did test it, and your results showed that it doesn't execute, and that you wanted a guarantee above and beyond your tests...

Comment: My test didn't throw an error which is good and i can probably rely on it, his test clearly show that its not reach that piece of code    Anyway i now know that i can just continue doing what i did.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at some more code. We'll test both scenarios:

1. First we will test for && by using two if statements
2. We'll use two Where calls

So:

```
var elements = new List<string>(new[] { "A", "B", "C" });

Console.WriteLine("C#'s &&");

elements.Where(x => {
    if (x == "A")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConditionA is true");
        if (1 == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ConditionB is true");
            return true;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("ConditionB is false");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("ConditionA is false");

    return false;           
}).ToList();

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Double Linq.Where");

elements.Where(x => {
    if (x == "A")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConditionA is true");
        return true;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("ConditionA is false");
    return false;           
})
    .Where(x => {
        if (1 == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ConditionB is true");
            return true;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("ConditionB is false");
        return false;
    }).ToList();
```

Here are the results:

```
C#'s &&
ConditionA is true
ConditionB is true
ConditionA is false
ConditionA is false

Double Linq.Where
ConditionA is true
ConditionB is true
ConditionA is false
ConditionA is false
```

As you can see, it's the same. Elements that don't pass ConditionA aren't tested for ConditionB.
You can try this out here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vals2r

Comment: Apparently [the OP already did this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53771135/linq-to-object-multiple-where-short-circuit-evaluation?noredirect=1#comment94394245_53771135) before asking this question.

Comment: @Servy Huh, I missed that comment while playing around. Thanks