# List.Where( "string".Contains()) returns NULL in a LINQ Query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

My `Product` class:

```
public class Product {
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string NameEnglish { get; set; }
 public string NameItalian { get; set; }
}
```

My `Language` class:

```
public class Language{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string LanguageType { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a method which searches in Products using "Name" properties and returns `List<Product>`:

```
List<Product> GetProductsFromSearch(int languageId, string searchedData){
    var products = _contex.Products.ToList();
    switch(languageId) //LanguageId 1 = English , LangaugeId 2 = Italian
    {
       case 1:
            return products.Where(i=>i.NameEnglish.Contains(searchedData)).ToList();
       case 2:
            return products.Where(i=>i.NameItalian.Contains(searchedData)).ToList();
       default:
            return products;
    }
}
```

The problem is, some of the products "English" or "Italian" name fields are not assigned in Db **yet**, so those are **null** fields.

And program gives error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

So I added an extra control which is :

```
return products.Where(i=> !string.isNullOrEmpty(i.NameEnglish) && 

                          i.NameEnglish.Contains(searchedData)).ToList()
```

But still I got the same **error**. Could someone help please? I got confused, shouldn't it **pass** the **null** fields?

**NOTE:**
 I know I should filtering directly in `_context.Products.Where(i=>i.NameEnglish.Contains(searchedData)).ToList();`
but this is for my **test** purposes, I'm trying to use "Where", in a "List" type.

```
Id | NameEnglish | NameItalian
1  | Ball        | Palla
2  | Phone       | Telefono
3  | Tshirt      | NULL
4  | NULL        | Bicchiere
```

**NOTE:** I had 12 rows now I have 4. (It didn't changed the result but I've deleted for you to see my table clearly)

Comment: Why are you doing `var products = _contex.Products.ToList()` that will result in pulling all the rows from the DB.  Why not determine which `Where` to do before calling `ToList` so that the code will be translated to SQL and done on the DB instead?

Comment: I know this is expensive, but for test purposes, I should return the values like this. This is a test project so there are small amount off values in my db.

Comment: And also I want to use "Where" where I have a type of "List" object.

Comment: There's no difference between your two 'case' statements.

Comment: Which line of code does the exception occur on? Also, please paste the exact code you are trying because `string.isNullOrEmpty` won't compile, it's `string.IsNullOrEmpty` It's hard to narrow down problems if you're trying to transcribe where you think the issue lies rather than providing the exact code.

Comment: @Sach the difference is `i.NameEnglish` vs `i.NameItalian`.

Comment: Oh OK. Just noticed.

Comment: I agree with @StevePy. That exception can result from a couple different lines here, so we need to know exactly which one is causing it

Comment: @Steve Py  ```return products.Where(i=>i.NameEnglish.Contains(searchedData)).ToList();``` this line directly throws the exception.

Comment: @Burak are you sure `products` is not null?

Comment: Yes I am sure..

Comment: Is it possible that `i` is somehow null (e.g. any of the items in `products` is null)?

Comment: @Matt U debugged like 100 times, and I have 12 products in my table, I can write my "Select" result if you want to see.

Comment: You inspected the `products` list in the debugger and they're all populated?

Comment: You mentioned adding a check for if `NameEnglish` is null but not if `NameItalian` is. Did you actually protect against either being null?

Comment: @Jacob There isnt a raw where they are both null.

Comment: @Matt U yes sir, they did populate.

Comment: @Burak: that's not my point. Did you fix _both_ `Where` clauses?

Comment: @Jacob Oh I see, yes I did sir.

Comment: Mind posting your full code where you add those checks, in case you made a slight mistake there? A potential mistake, for example might have been checking if `NameEnglish` was null in both where clauses instead of one checking `NameEnglish` and the other checking `NameItalian`. It has to be an issue in the where clause. Also are you sure `searchedData` isn't null?

Comment: Can you please edit title of the post to make sense - `.Where` *never* returns `null`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a null conditional operator if all those items are indeed **not** null. It's cleaner than a null check, IMO:

```c#
products.Where(p => p.NameEnglish?.Contains(searchedData) == true);
```

Likewise for `NameItalian`.

Comment: Trying immediately.

Comment: If you change both and still have an issue, something else is going on and it can't be these lines.

Comment: Okay Matt this worked, but what was the difference between  "!= null , string.isNullOrEmpty(str) " and this one? Can you please explain?

Comment: Appears to be a lesser known behavior of LINQ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/772283/12431728 ... Short-circuit evaluation doesn't occur the way one may expect.

Comment: @MattU But in this case it's definitely being using in Linq-to-Objects.

Comment: @juharr Yes, I noticed that, but it seems to be the same case.

Comment: One other difference is if `NameEnglish` is empty and `searchedData` is empty then this will result in `true` while the `IsNullOrEmpty` should result in `false`.

Comment: null coalesce as `p => . . . ) ?? false == true` would fix that, but I've gotten into the practice of doing verbose null checking due to always using LINQ-to-SQL and having to manage those limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
List<Product> GetProductsFromSearch(int languageId, string searchedData){
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchedData))
       return new List<Product>();

   var query = _contex.Products; 

    switch(languageId) //LanguageId 1 = English , LangaugeId 2 = Italian
    {
       case 1:
            query = query.Where(i=>i.NameEnglish.Contains(searchedData));
       case 2:
            query = query.Where(i=>i.NameItalian.Contains(searchedData));
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

If this raises an error, please provide the exact exception details and any inner exception. The above should work and when passed to EF2SQL it should handle the potential for the names to be null.

As you mention, you want to load from the List. In this case you would need to assert the null check:

```
List<Product> GetProductsFromSearch(int languageId, string searchedData){
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchedData))
       return new List<Product>();

   var query = _contex.Products.ToList(); 

    switch(languageId) //LanguageId 1 = English , LangaugeId 2 = Italian
    {
       case 1:
            query = query.Where(i=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.NameEnglish) && i.NameEnglish.Contains(searchedData));
       case 2:
            query = query.Where(i=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.NameItalian) && i.NameItalian.Contains(searchedData));
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

I suspect your attempt may have failed if you mistyped/copy-paste an issue with a null check against the wrong name value for a different language. I.e. `IsNullOrEmpty` against the English name but did the `Contains` on the Italian one.

Answer (score 0):

Try `i=>i.NameItalian != null && i.NameItalian.Contains(searchedData)` and likewise for the English one.

Comment: OP said they added that check.

Comment: Yes I added this one and string.isNullOrEmpty checks

Comment: I didn't see the `!= null`, only the `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` which are *really* different from the perspective of Entity Framework.

Comment: But this stuff isn't going to EF because they OP does a `ToList` before they apply the `Where`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a logger to your context just for debugging purposes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception

You can then see what exact queries get generated and which exact query causes an issue. Sometimes the translation to sql doesn't work exactly like you think.

Comment: Thak you, I ll add.

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to a simple factor.  You have to understand the flow of your assignment logic. NPEs always deal with variable asignments of which can be several reasons. Linq as a Any() which can be used to test a condition on a IEnumerable before having to pull its results. This may help you to device a proper handle for this exception.