# AD Group not found System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need some clarification here. I'm trying to verify a group in a string of in a IEnumerable of objects. The code as follows:

### Startup.cs

```
// Makes a call to Microsoft Graph
var group = await graphClient.Me.TransitiveMemberOf
    .Request()
    .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
    .GetAsync();

// Gets all AD Groups that are assigned to me
IEnumerable<AzureADGroupInfo> allADGroups = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<AzureADGroupInfo>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(group));

//This filters the group that I Need
IEnumerable<AzureADGroupInfo> relevantADGroups = allADGroups.Where(t => t.DisplayName.Contains("Admin"));

this.SetUserCompany(relevantADGroups);
```

In the allADGroups gets like 10 groups that I'm associated with but the one group I want is the Admin group. In debugging, Admin group exists in the allADGroups variable but for whatever reason in the where clause to find t.DisplayName.Contains("Admin") it doesn't find it. It comebacks null for revelantADGroups variable. To my understanding this should be able to find that group display name in the IEnumerable. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Your question is not clear as to what is causing the NullReferenceException. You seem to think it is because relevantADGroups is null. But it could be other things. For instance, `this` could be null, or `group` could be null. Or it could be something in SetUserCompany. Or anywhere really ... a NullReferenceException is not at all the same thing as something being null - you have to reference the null thing to get the exception.

Comment: Well debugging it I get allADGroups that I'm associated with but since I'm concerned with Admin group I filter it by Displayname if it contains Admin in the string. In this case it should but revelantADGroups comes back null. That is why it is throwing an exception error. Does that make sense? The this.SetUserCompany is a method that I have to do other extra logic on it.

Comment: No, not really clear. A method that returns null is not the same thing as throwing a NullReferenceException. You are not showing where the exception occurs. If you are wondering why you are getting null from your linq expression, we don't have enough detail to give an answer - it depends on the data, which we don't have any examples of.

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure AD Graph API, in the REST response, the **displayName** property should be camelCase (not "DisplayName"), otherwise it will not be found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question to see if anybody was facing a similar issue. While the code above brings back all the groups in Azure AD and tries to filter with .Contains("Admin"), however it shows this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

The solution I found that help me out big time was found here [List.Where( "string".Contains()) returns NULL in a LINQ Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59205044/list-where-string-contains-returns-null-in-a-linq-query). In short I made the change to forcibly say that all the groups in Azure AD are indeed not null. Hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).