# Multiple character comparisons, how can I write it smarter?

Tags: c, coding-style, char

I am parsing a text-file. While parsing, I want to skip certain characters (space, line-break, comma, period). In PHP, one may check the existence of a variable in an array with `in_array(char, array)`, but things are obviously different given we are working with pointers.

I am currently writing it like this (excuse the weird formatting)

```
if (c == ' '  || 
    c == '\n' || 
    c == '.'  || 
    c == ',') {

  continue;
}
```

But it feels a bit dumb. Is there a smarter/more compact way to perform multiple comparisons like this?

Comment: Hard to guess what's "dumb" about it.  Maybe you ought to write a one-liner isPunctuation(char) function.  Maybe you shouldn't [try too hard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124620/why-does-msvc-emit-a-useless-movsx-before-performing-this-bit-test).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another choice would be to use [`strchr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strrchr.3.html) to check if a given character is in a given string:

```
if (strchr(" \n.,", c)
    continue;
```

Comment: Note: `c` will match the 4 desired `char`: `' '`, `'\n'`, `'.'`, `','` and  `'\0'`.

Comment: @krystah If if it's time critical, your solution may still be better than the strchr solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
switch(c) {
  case ' ':
  case '\n':
  case '.:
  case ',':
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a function and pass a string with your characters:

```
_Bool Check( char a , char* str )
{
    while( *str )
    { 
        if( *str == a )
        {
            return true ;
        }

        str++ ;
    }

return false ;
}

Check( c , ",.\n " ) ;
```